# How to get parent controller from uiviewcontainer's controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

This is my setup :

[image: UIViewController with a UIViewContainer]

I have a UIViewController with inside a UIViewContainer that displays a UITableViewController.

When someone press a cell from the UITableViewController, I do some processing then I want to dismiss the parent UIViewController but I don't have access to it.

I tried, within UITableViewController, the following :

```
self.parentViewController //It is nil
self.presentingViewController //It is nil
```

The project is under Xcode 6 for iOS7 and iOS8. I am working in **Swift**.

Comment: `parentingViewController` is only not nil if the presentation was done modally and then it is the view controller which initiated the modal presentation.

Comment: can you tell how your tableViewController is connected with UIViewController.

Comment: I dragged'n'dropped a container inside the UIViewController from the Storyboard. It automatically created a View Controller with an embed segue. So I replaced it with a TableViewController.

Comment: Please check you segue type it should be embed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going old school with a property parentDelegate/childDelegate.

```
//In the parent
class ParentViewController: UIViewController {
    var child: ChildViewController?

    //Set the child delegate
    //And child's parent delegate
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "embedTable" {
            self.child = (segue.destinationViewController as ChildViewController)
            (segue.destinationViewController as ChildViewController).parent = self
        }
    }

    //After dismissing view, set delegates to nil so they can correctly release
    func exit() {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {() in
            self.child?.parent = nil
            self.child = nil
        })
    }
}

//In the child
class ChildViewController: UITableViewController {
    var parent: ParentViewController?
}
```